# create-react-app - why discrepancy with version listed between NPM and Github?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

On the NPM registry, create-react-app version is listed as 1.4.3.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app

On Github, the latest version is listed as 1.0.17.

- https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Why is there a discrepancy, and how can I correlate the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check here: `https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/create-react-app/package.json`

inside there is the version property... with value 1.4.3

Comment: Thanks! One last question - why would the version numbers be different? Why not go off the package in the readme?

Comment: npm has its version. github version is a different thing... you can create for example many versions in github and then decide to push to npm, that doesn't mean you will create each version from GH into npm

Comment: Thanks again! Wish they would note the corresponding npm version on Github so I relate to a specific NPM version.

Comment: Actually, I found more clarifying info: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#updating-to-new-releases ... the package is made up of two packages, and in my question, I was conflating `react-scripts` and `create-react-app`... could you update your answer with this info?

Comment: you should create another question as it is a different one, but in `https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/package.json` the version is 1.0.17. in npm that package is 1.0.17 and in GH is same version in that case. you can write any version inside the package.json and push to npm and it will take that version, it doesn't take the version from GH. HTH